# Botframework with NodeJS while prompt system doesn't read what user input the value

Tags: node.js, botframework

Azure BotFramework
SDK4
NodeJS

In dialog state I am using 'return await step.prompt' inside async function. But once user enters the value it is not considering the user input value as a input for prompt instead it is going to luisrecognizer for the match.

I have written the similar code for different dialog where it works fine.

Kindly requesting you provide some valuable input.

Azure BotFramework
SDK4
NodeJS

```
this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog('OrderStatusDialog', [
   async function(step) {
     return await step.context.sendActivity(reply);
   },
   async function(step) {
     var cardValue = step.context.activity.value;
     if (cardValue) {
        if (cardValue.action == "Order_Number") {
           return await step.prompt('textPrompt', 'enter order number');
        } else if (cardValue.action == "Serial_Number") {
           return await step.prompt('textPrompt', 'enter serial number');
        } else {
        }
     }
     return await step.next();
     // return await step.endDialog();
  },
  async function (step) {
     var cardValue = step.context.activity;
     console.log("****** cardValue");
     console.log(cardValue);
     console.log("****** step After");
     console.log(step);
     return await step.endDialog();
  }
]));
```

at prompt step it should read the value what user is entering. Also stack is empty when i console the step ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have a few issues with your code. But, hopefully this will help iron them out. I had no issues running the below code.

One, double check which version of Botbuilder you have installed. At least one call ('this.addDialog') I am unfamiliar with, doesn't appear to be a part of the current SDK, and didn't work for me when testing.

Two, configure your bot like below. Technically, you should be able pass the various steps in as you have them in your question. However, something about yours was not work and I couldn't figure out what. The below setup DOES work, however, and conforms to already accepted practices.

Three, your first step calls 'step.context.sendActivity(reply)'. In the next step you are trying to read the returned value of that call. That isn't going to work as sendActivity simply sends a statement from the bot to the user ("Welcome to my bot!", for example). You need to perform a prompt to capture the user's input response (see below).

It looks like you are trying to read a value from a card. Since you didn't supply that bit of code, I faked the value by supplying the 'Order_Number' and 'Serial_Number' via a text prompt from the user.

You should also take advantage of the bot state options. Rather than use the variable 'cardValue', consider using UserState or DialogState to store user values important to the conversation.

Lastly, in this simple example, order and serial numbers will overwrite each other if you pass thru multiple times.

```js
const START_DIALOG = 'starting_dialog';
const DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY = 'dialogState';
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'user';

const ACTION_PROMPT = 'action_prompt';
const ORDER_PROMPT= 'order_prompt';
const SERIAL_PROMPT= 'serial_prompt';
...

class ExampleBot {
    constructor(conversationState, userState) {
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;

        this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);

        this.userData = this.userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

        this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);

        this.dialogs
            .add(new TextPrompt(ACTION_PROMPT))
            .add(new TextPrompt(ORDER_PROMPT))
            .add(new TextPrompt(SERIAL_PROMPT));

        this.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog(START_DIALOG, [
            this.promptForAction.bind(this),
            this.promptForNumber.bind(this),
            this.consoleLogResult.bind(this)
        ]));
    }

    async promptForAction(step) {
        return await step.prompt(ACTION_PROMPT, `Action?`,
            {
                retryPrompt: 'Try again. Action??'
            }
        );
    }

    async promptForNumber(step) {
        const user = await this.userData.get(step.context, {});
        user.action = step.result;
        if (user) {
            if (user.action == 'Order_Number') {
                return await step.prompt(ORDER_PROMPT, 'enter order number');
            } else if (user.action == 'Serial_Number') {
                return await step.prompt(SERIAL_PROMPT, 'enter serial number');
            } else {
            }
        }
        return await step.next();
    }

    async consoleLogResult(step) {
        const user = await this.userData.get(step.context, {});
        user.orderNumber = step.result;
        console.log('****** cardValue');
        console.log(user);
        console.log('****** step After');
        console.log(step);
        return await step.endDialog();
    }

    async onTurn(turnContext) {

    ... //Other code

    // Save changes to the user state.
    await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);

    // End this turn by saving changes to the conversation state.
    await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext);

    }
}
```

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

somehow it worked for me after saving conversation state where ever i am replacing the dialog.

```
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to save conversationState following every replace dialog action. The fact that you do indicates that you your code is structured incorrectly. Did you try structuring your code like the example I provided?